# C++ Boost function callback. How to invoke function as a callback and pass params inside?

Tags: c++, function, boost, callback

I have class `Manager` and class `Scheduler`. `Manager` has `Scheduler`'s instance. `Manager` launch `Scheduler`. `Scheduler` doing something, and `Scheduler` must return result to `Manager` asynchronously. How I can make it like down below in example?

```
class Manager{
private:
    Scheduler *mScheduler;

public:
    Manager(){
        mScheduler = new Scheduler(boost::bind(&Manager::acceptResult, this));
        mScheduler->run();
    }

    void acceptResult(Result::Shared result){
        //do something with result, it's doesn't matter=)
    }
};

typedef boost::function<void()> callback;

class Scheduler {
private:
    callback mManagerCallback;

public:
    Scheduler(callback call){
        mManagerCallback = call;
    }

    void run(){
        //some logic
        mManagerCallback(result);
    }

}

typedef boost::posix_time::ptime Timestamp;
typedef boost::posix_time::time_duration Duration;
typedef uint64_t microseconds_timestamp;

class CommandResult {
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<const CommandResult> SharedConst;

private:
    CommandUUID mCommandUUID;
    uint16_t mResultCode;
    Timestamp mTimestampCompleted;
    string mResultInformation;

public:
    CommandResult(
            const CommandUUID &commandUUID,
            const uint16_t resultCode);

    CommandResult(
            const CommandUUID &commandUUID,
            const uint16_t resultCode,
            string &resultInformation);

    const CommandUUID &commandUUID() const;

    const uint16_t resultCode() const;

    const Timestamp &timestampCompleted() const;

    const string serialize() const;

};
```

CommandResult it's same as a result in example.

I need when `Scheduler` make result, in him method `run()`, invoke `Manager`'s method `acceptResult()` and pass result as a parameter. I'm new to C++ and I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: As you have found out, it's important to have a [simple, self contained example](http://sscce.org/). Your updated example code is still incomplete because it mixes names and doesn't include the required headers etc. It's silly to expect people who COULD help you to waste time coming up with those things. It'll just cause them to ignore your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to make it so that a callback *can* take a parameter:

```
typedef boost::function<void(CommandResult::SharedConst)> callback;
```

Then you need to match that signature in the bind. It looks like you want to leave the result free for binding from within the `Scheduler::run()` logic, so let's use a placeholder:

```
 mScheduler = new Scheduler(boost::bind(&Manager::acceptResult, this, ::_1));
```

Now in your logic, you somehow make a result and you just pass that down to the callback:

```
void run(){
    boost::uuids::random_generator rgen;
    CommandResult::SharedConst result(new CommandResult(rgen(), 404u, "Not found"));
    //some logic
    mManagerCallback(result);
}
```

Full demo: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru (C++03)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92a033c883ad4004)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/random_generator.hpp>

typedef boost::posix_time::ptime Timestamp;
typedef boost::posix_time::time_duration Duration;
typedef uint64_t microseconds_timestamp;

typedef boost::uuids::uuid CommandUUID;

class CommandResult {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<const CommandResult> SharedConst;

private:
    CommandUUID mCommandUUID;
    uint16_t mResultCode;
    Timestamp mTimestampCompleted;
    std::string mResultInformation;

public:
    CommandResult(
            const CommandUUID &commandUUID,
            const uint16_t resultCode,
            std::string const &resultInformation = "")
      : mCommandUUID(commandUUID),
        mResultCode(resultCode),
        mTimestampCompleted(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()),
        mResultInformation(resultInformation)
    { }

    const CommandUUID &commandUUID() const { return mCommandUUID; }
    uint16_t resultCode() const { return mResultCode; }
    const Timestamp &timestampCompleted() const { return mTimestampCompleted; }
};

typedef boost::function<void(CommandResult::SharedConst)> callback;

class Scheduler {
private:
    callback mManagerCallback;

public:
    Scheduler(callback call){
        mManagerCallback = call;
    }

    void run(){
        boost::uuids::random_generator rgen;
        CommandResult::SharedConst result(new CommandResult(rgen(), 404u, "Not found"));
        //some logic
        mManagerCallback(result);
    }
};

#include <iostream>

class Manager{
private:
    Scheduler *mScheduler;

public:
    Manager(){
        //mScheduler = new Scheduler([this](CommandResult::SharedConst result) { acceptResult(result); });
        mScheduler = new Scheduler(boost::bind(&Manager::acceptResult, this, ::_1));
        mScheduler->run();
    }

    void acceptResult(CommandResult::SharedConst result){
        //do something with result, it's doesn't matter=)
        std::cout << "Accepted: " << result->commandUUID() << ", " << result->resultCode() << ": " << result->timestampCompleted() << " \n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Manager m;
}
```

Prints:

```
Accepted: cf946fb0-49f3-425a-8235-558d19bf6f8d, 404: 2016-Dec-23 12:18:01
```

### Bonus: C++11

Bind is a bit of an anachronism (although I sometimes quite like it, for rare jobs), so consider using a lambda instead:

```
mScheduler = new Scheduler([this](CommandResult::SharedConst result) { acceptResult(result); });
```

Comment: In your example result is a simple structure with single primitive type field member. When I create callback's type mask typedef boost::function<void(Result::Shared)> callback; and then define member mManagerCallback as a callback type IDE says, that instantiating as unknown structure without a reference.

Comment: I think your comment is incomplete? Also, just post a complete question with complete code. I made up `Result` because you didn't include it. You can't really comment on this answer based on the fact that your `Result` is different...

Comment: @DenisMakovsky the usual route is to post a new question, because it's bad style to invalidate the existing answer(s). I'll look at it briefly though

Comment: I'm having to guess, because nowhere do you show how you construct the `CommandResult`, but likely you're passing it a `"reason"` and because the parameter is not `const&` it doesn't compile. Anyhow, here's a full demo that does work **[Live On Coliru (C++03)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92a033c883ad4004)** printing: `Accepted: cf946fb0-49f3-425a-8235-558d19bf6f8d, 404: 2016-Dec-23 12:18:01`

Comment: can I use not boost shred_ptr with boost function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131344/discussion-between-sehe-and-denis-makovsky).